# Ckedior: Redo and undo plugin is not reseting its stack

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I am using Ckeditor to edit my HTML pages, and I am loading the HTML into Ckeditor with ajax, which works perfectly fine.
But while loading a page into Ckeditor, i want to reset the redo-undo stack of the Ckeditor,

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.resetUndo();
```

Using the above statement, my undo and redo buttons are getting disabled until my next edit, but the stack of the old operations is not reset.

The reset function looks like

```
   a.resetUndo = function() {
        b.reset();
        a.fire("saveSnapshot")
    };
    reset: function()
 {

    this.lastKeystroke = 0;

    this.snapshots = [];
    this.index = -1;
    this.limit = this.editor.config.undoStackSize || 20;
    this.currentImage = null;
    this.hasRedo = this.hasUndo = !1;
    this.locked = null;
    this.resetType();
},
```

`this.snapshots` is the stack that I want to reset.

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a mid way of doing this,
you can manage to reset the redo-undo stack of CKEDITOR by reset the object of the CKEditor,
To do so,

1. Create the CKE object using a function, means write the script of
   `CKEDITOR.replace();` into a function.
2. use `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.destroy()` to remove the Old CKeditor object form memory.

Once the object is removed from memory, it will reset the redo undo stack.

I know its not the correct method to solve this problem, but it will help (HOPE SO).